# RSS Feed & Special Characters

Tags: php, xml, rss, special-characters, htmlspecialchars

I have been working for hours on trying to get a rss feed. The problem is with special characters. I have data listed as a list on the website, but I want a rss feed also. The title has "&" which are written as $amp;. If I use htmlspecialchars it converts it to $amp;amp; if I don't the validator gives an error because of the "&". I can't write "&" or the html will not display it correctly. I try to leave it alone and put it in a Cdata tag but that did not work either.

Here is the feed: http://montanafarmersunion.com/rss.php

Here is the html of the same list: http://montanafarmersunion.com/?hd=news&id=news

Comment: Show us your code. We can't help without seeing what you have tried.

Comment: Here is the line in question `<title><![CDATA[ '.trim( htmlspecialchars($art[1],ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8')).' ]]></title>` The art[1] is a from an array and the text is like this `August 1st: MFU President on farm bill`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [RSS Advisory Board page](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-profile#data-types-characterdata) sums up the problem fairly nicely:

> The specification has lacked clarity regarding whether HTML is
>   permitted in elements other than an item's description, leading to
>   wide variance in how aggregators treat character data in other
>   elements. This makes it especially difficult for a publisher to
>   determine how to encode the characters "&" and "<", which must be
>   encoded in XML.

Which is to say, there isn't a 'right' way. In theory, you should be able to get away with not using the CDATA tags, and then HTML encoding your title. For example, this works for me in Firefox & IE8:

```php
$title = 'August 1st: MFU President &amp; friends on farm bill';
echo '<title>'.trim($title).'</title>';
```

However the [W3 RSS validator](http://validator.w3.org/appc/) (is this what you are using?) recommends against it because of the `&amp;`, based on the page linked above. They suggest using the hexadecimal character reference, but only for `&` and `<`. The easiest way to implement this is probably a simple `str_replace`:

```
$title = 'August 1st: MFU President & friends on farm bill';
$title = str_replace(array('&', '<'), array('&#x26;', '&#x3C;'), $title);
echo '<title>'.trim($title).'</title>';
```

(note I've made the starting string a bare `&`)

I feel compelled to mention [this blog post](http://www.xn--8ws00zhy3a.com/blog/2006/06/encoding-rss-titles) as well, which demonstrates that there isn't really a way to make all readers happy all of the time. But the last method should get most of them.